# Reading with MySqlDataReader

Tags: c#, mysql, connector

Hello I'm having problem to read with `MySqlDataReader`. I've tried to change `while()` to `if()` and it worked then. So I'm doing something wrong with `while (Reader.Read())`. Thanks for answer. ( The other question today is fixed, someone that commented helped me xd )

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand
      ("SELECT * FROM `citationer`",  mysqlCon))
{
    try
    {
        MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (Reader.Read()) // this part is wrong somehow
        {
            citationstexter.Add(Reader.GetString(loopReading)); // this works
            loopReading++; // this works
        }
        Reader.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the exception details please. It seems fine to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the use of the `loopReading` parameter to `GetString`.
This parameter should be the zero-based column ordinal (the column number), but you're incrementing it for every row you read.

See here for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx

You should use 0 for the first column of your citationer table, 1 for the second column, etc.

Also, it's good practice to use

```
  using(MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
  {
    ...
  }
```

just like you did for the mySqlCommand object to save a memory leak (but this is not your problem.)