# Connection to MySql using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

I am running this function in the Load Form to display the information from my database to dataGridView in c#. The problem is that the form pop up before it tries to access ad retrieve the data. Here is how it runs in debugger. I run the function below.

```
public void loadData()
{
    var list = mysql.Select();
    try
    {
        //start from first row
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            //insert IDs
            dataGridView1[0, i].Value = list[0][i];
            //insert Names
            dataGridView1[1, i].Value = list[1][i];
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                if (list[3][j] != null)
                {
                    dataGridView1[j + 2, i].Value = list[3][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And then it calls the Select function in mysql class and stop at MySqlDataReader and pop up the Window Form. Can someone tell me what was happing?

Here is the Mysql.Select()

```
public List <string> [] Select()
{
    string query = "SELECT id,name,weekday,description FROM employee e INNER JOIN schedule s ON e.id=s.id";

    //Create a list to store the result
    List<string>[] list = new List<string>[4];
    list[0] = new List<string>();
    list[1] = new List<string>();
    list[2] = new List<string>();
    list[3] = new List<string>();

    //Open connection
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        //Create Command
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        //Create a data reader and Execute the command
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //Read the data and store them in the list
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            list[0].Add(dataReader["id"] + "");
            list[1].Add(dataReader["name"] + "");
            list[2].Add(dataReader["weekday"] + "");
            list[3].Add(dataReader["description"] + "");
        }

        //close Data Reader
        dataReader.Close();

        //close Connection
        this.CloseConnection();

        //return list to be displayed
        return list;
    }
    else
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace meaningless title with concrete subject of your question, please.

Comment: @AaronLS he/she just removed that code - its in the `form_load`

Comment: what do you mean by stop? Does it hit a break point you set there?  Is there an error? Have you tried putting a break point on the line with while(dataReader.Read())?

Comment: in the Select funtion, it runs successfully until it reaches MySqlDataReader and displays the Form without getting into the while loop.

Comment: if there are no records returned from your cmd.ExecuteReader() then dataReader.Read() will return false. Are you sure you are getting data back from your database?

Comment: how do I know there are values returning. I see a similar problem, but don't understand what to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606643/reading-with-mysqldatareader

Comment: Comment out the body of your loop and replace it with var id = dataReader.GetInt(0);  put a break point on that line and see if it gets hit. This way you will be able to tell if you are getting data.

Comment: I place your code right after declare the MySqlDataReader. It hits the MysqlDataReader dataReader line and displays the form. It does not reach your code.

Answer (score 3):

While its processing the MySQL command and fetching info from the Database it appears the application has been given time to paint the form.

Simple fix is to do it like this:

```
    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          this.visible = false;
          loadData();
          this.visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: it still pops up the Form  at MySqlDataReader. What else would I do?

Comment: Put the `Select()` code into `try` `catch` I think there is a Null Exception there